# Limit of a sequence ${a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let {${a_n}$} be a sequence of real numbers and $a \ne 0$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n} = a$   iff  $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{a-a_n}{a+a_n}) = 0$

My approach:

Forward direction:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{a-a_n}{a+a_n})$

$= (\frac{a-a}{a+a}) $

$= 0$

I don't know how to show the implication in the other direction. Also is my approach for the forward direction correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   if $\,\frac{a-a_n}{a+a_n} = \frac{2a}{a+a_n}-1 \to 0\,$ then $\,\frac{2a}{a+a_n} \to 1\,$ so $\,\frac{a+a_n}{2a} \to 1\,$ and $\;\ldots$

Comment: $a_n = a$? Also is my forward direction approach correct?

Comment: @The.Shark Right, you get $\require{cancel}\,\frac{\cancel{a}}{2\cancel{a}}+\frac{a_n}{2a} \to 1\,$, so  $\,\frac{a_n}{2a} \to \frac{1}{2}\,$, so  $\,a_n \to \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2a\,$. The forward approach is correct, it all follows from the basic properties of sums/differences/ratios of convergent sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n=\frac {a-a_n}{a+a_n}.$ Then $a_n=\frac {a(1-b_n)}{1+b_n}.$ If $b_n\to  0$ then by the forward direction  we have $$a=a\cdot 1=a\cdot \lim_n\frac {1-b_n}{1+b_n}=\lim_n\frac {a(1-b_n)}{1+b_n}=\lim_n a_n.$$